# Where I can find Go+BoringCrypto README after it moves to master branch?

Tags: go

Go's [dev.boringcrypto](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/dev.boringcrypto/README.boringcrypto.md) branch has moved to `master` branch, hence this branch is not used anymore.

Unfortunately, [misc/boring/README.md](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dev.boringcrypto/misc/boring/README.md) file does not exist in `master` branch. So, where I can find this README now? *Already searching in `master` branch but could not find the equivalent README.

I'm searching information for Go+BoringCrypto Docker image.

Comment: Unfortunately [https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/dev.boringcrypto/README.boringcrypto.md](/README.boringcrypto.md) mentions that `This branch is no more. GOEXPERIMENT=boringcrypto on the standard branch does the job now.`

I'm also looking at RELEASES files but it does not exist in master anymore
https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/dev.boringcrypto/misc/boring/RELEASES